# MongoDB add event

Tags: ruby, mongodb, node.js

Is it possible to somehow subscribe to 'add to db' event using Node.js? Database is currently populated via Ruby on Rails. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MongoDB** wise

There's an ongoing discussion about [triggers](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-124) on mongodb Jira.

But for now you're stuck with storing auto-increment values alongside with your data, and using indexed queries to check if there's anything new.

**Rails** wise

I'm assuming you're using Mongoid. Use callbacks or [observers](http://mongoid.org/docs/callbacks/observers.html) to send messages to a fast capped collection / unix socket / whatever. Other ODMs shouldn't be too different.

Answer (score 0):

You need to notify the Node.js process from the Rails app when you insert something in the DB.

1. Listen on a socket/port from Node.js process
2. From Rails write on that socket when record added
3. From Node, process each message on the socket